# Returned Value From Computed Property Doesn't Change When It's Used In Template (Vue3 without Composition API)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to get an item's width in a computed property to pass it to CSS variable.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <fieldset>
    <legend :style="`--gap:${legendGap}px`"></legend>
  </fieldset>
  <label>{{ label }}</label>
  <input/>
</div>
```

```
computed: {
  legendGap() {
    if (
      !this.$el ||
      this.label == '' ||
      !this.design == 'outlined' ||
      !this.options.some((x) => ['has-placeholder', 'is-dirty', 'is-focused'].includes(x))
    ) {
      return 0;
    }
    return (
      parseFloat(
        window.getComputedStyle(this.$el.querySelector('label')).getPropertyValue('width')
      ) * 0.8
    );
}
```

If I remove `` :style="`--gap:${legendGap}px`" `` from template or change the variable name, computed property returns correct value, otherwise it returns 0. So somehow, using the computed property in the template locks its value. I haven't seen anything like that before. I assume that using $el causes the problem, but I'm not sure.

How can I make the computed property returns the correct value without removing the variable from template?

Comment: I think the reason is the `window.getComputedStyle(...)` part is not reactive, so `legendGap` stays at the value when it's first accessed

Comment: But it changes, if I don't use it in template.

Comment: My best guess would be: when you use it in template, `legendGap` is evaluated immediately when the template is ready, at the time it returns 0 somehow. AND when you removed `legendGap` from your template, `legendGap` won't be evaluated util the time you opens the devtool and check the value, at that time, some conditions/variables have changed, thus it returns the data you wanted. You can add the `console.log` in the `legendGap()` to confirm

Comment: But computed property should remain reactive. I tried using the watcher and assign the computed value to the data attribute and use it in the template. Didn't work. So whenever I touch legendGap it stuck at 0. That's so strange.

Comment: computed property is reactive only when all the variables used to compute value are reactive, i.e. data, props, computed properties. In your code, `this.$el` is not reactive, and window API is also not reactive, so `legendGap` is of course not reactive, but it might be re-evaluated (if accessed) if `this.label`, `this.design` and `this.options` are modified since these properties are reactive. Reactivity basically means things that Vue can detect changes from, so it certainly has limitations and does not apply to anything that outside the Vue itself.

Comment: I think you can try a different approach, add a watcher for `label` property and calculate `legendGap` in the watcher

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED, sorry I fixed a few script errors, I think it should be good now, let me know if you still have issues.

=========

Maybe try a different approach like this, I just hand coded it, you may double check for typos etc.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <fieldset>
    <legend :style="`--gap:${legendGap}px`"></legend>
  </fieldset>
  <label ref="label">{{ label }}</label>
  <input/>
</div>
```

```
data() {
  return {
    legendGap: 0
  }
},
watch: {
  label() {
    this.calcLegendGap()
  }
},
mounted() {
  // needed to set the init value after all rendered
  this.calcLegendGap()
},
methods: {
  calcLegendGap() {
    if (
      !this.label ||
      this.design !== 'outlined' ||
      !this.options.some((x) => ['has-placeholder', 'is-dirty', 'is-focused'].includes(x))
    ) {
      this.legendGap = 0;
    } else {
      // $nextTick is required we need to wait for DOM update
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.legendGap = parseFloat(
          window.getComputedStyle(this.$refs.label).getPropertyValue('width')
        ) * 0.8;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lin. I solve my issue thanks to your last comment under the question. I simply added ```gap: false``` to data and in the mounted hook, I made it true. Since I added it as a new condition in legendGap, it was fired. It seems easier than your current suggestion. So I will stick with it, but if you update your answer accordingly, I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: @BülentAkgül, no worries, you can leave it as it is, since I don't know what other logic you might have in your component so yeah you can just go whatever you feel comfort with, the reason above code might look more complicated because it deals with reactivity (anytime when `label` changes, the `legendGap` will be updated accordingly)